# Nivo Slider on back of the content Controls Z-Index Cant click / external controls

Tags: controls, slider, z-index, nivo-slider

I have a site that I'm bulding with a nivo slider on back of the contentand horizontal wide, everything work fine but the controls "arrows" and "bullets" are not working fine.

example: http://www.aiguapool.mx/test/

In IE 8 and IE9 you can click and works but in firefox and chrome dont do any thing, is like some div is covering and don't let users to click the buttons. Nivo Slider is almost untouched , I just created a wrapper for nivo slider that contains this CCS code

```
.slider-wrap {<br>
    overflow: hidden;<br>
    position: absolute;<br>
    width: 1490px;<br>
    height: 535px;<br>
    top: 80px;<br>
    left: 50%;<br>
    margin-left: -745px;<br>
    z-index: -1;<br>
}
```

So my question is why on IE is working and not in Firefox and Chrome even Safari and if there's something that I'm missing, other way I tried is to generate an external control but didn't worked (the controls not respond) ex.

```
$("#previousButton, #nextButton").click(function (e) {

         // Prevent the link from being followed
         e.preventDefault();

         // Initialize variables 
         var buttonId = this.id,
          buttonClass = ("previousButton" == buttonId) ? ".nivo-prevNav" : ".nivo-nextNav";

         // Trigger the slider button
         $(".nivo-directionNav").find(buttonClass).click();
    });

$("#triangleNodePrev").click(function(){$(".nivo-directionNav .nivo-prevNav").click()})
$("#triangleNodeNext").click(function(){$(".nivo-directionNav .nivo-nextNav").click()})

$(".nivo-directionNav .nivo-prevNav").click()

$(".nivo-directionNav .nivo-nextNav").click()
```

and create a link `<a href="#" id="previousButton">Back</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved after many tries. I have to mention that I use grid system, so i have 1 container on top for the Header, and one container on bottom for the content.

So I tweaked the CSS for the container of the content:

```
.container_content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -540px;
    width: 1050px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background: url(../images/estructura/bg-content-albercas.png) no-repeat;
    min-height: 200px;
    top: 560px;
    left: 50%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    z-index:99;
}
```

and everything worked just fine.